# Does C++Builder 12.0 support C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, module, c++20, c++builder, c++builder-12-athens

RAD Studio 12.0 has been released, and they supposedly upgraded C++Builder to Clang 15, but I can't find the module feature of C++20, is there any explanation?

Comment: looking at the website I can only see C++17 support from version 12, and modules were released in C++20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Clang 15 upgrade only applies to the [Windows 64bit preview compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/BCC64X), not to the rest of C++Builder's compilers, which are still based on Clang 3.3 and 5.0.

Per C++Builder 12.0's documentation:

[Clang-enhanced C++ Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)

> RAD Studio provides the following Clang-enhanced C++ compilers:
>
> | Compiler | Platform | Clang Version | LLVM Version |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | BCC32C | 32-bit Windows | 5.0 | 5.0 |
> | BCC32X | 32-bit Windows | 5.0 | 5.0 |
> | BCC64 | 64-bit Windows | 5.0 | 5.0 |
> | BCC64X | 64-bit Windows | 15.0 | 15.0 |
> | BCCIOSARM64 | 64-bit iOS | 3.3 | 3.5 |
> | BCCAARM | Android | 3.3 | 3.3 |

Also:

[Modern C++ Language Features Compliance Status](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Modern_C%2B%2B_Language_Features_Compliance_Status)

> Note: C++2c is expected to be C++26.

> Note: BCC64X is currently a Preview. The below status is aspirational but untested and is not a guarantee of the final support. **BCC64X uses C++17 as its default language level, and the initial release is not planned to support higher language levels.** To compile to C++2c, run bcc64x with `-std=c++2c`.

> Note: **C++23 is partially supported by the Clang version that BCC64X is based on and the C++ RTL and STL (libc+) that it uses. We expect that any language feature supported by both the Clang and the libc++ in versions 15 and earlier, work correctly. But it is not supported, even at the unsupported level that a Preview implies.** However, the Preview of the BCC64X compiler currently aims at C++17 as its language standard. You can use `-std=c++23` to change the target language compliance.

> Note: **C++20 is partially supported by the Clang version that BCC64X is based on and the C++ RTL and STL (libc++) that it uses. We expect that any language feature supported by both the Clang and the libc++ in versions 15 and earlier, work correctly. But it is not supported, even at the unsupported level that a Preview implies.** However, the Preview of the BCC64X compiler currently aims at C++17 as its language standard. You can use `-std=c++20` to change the target language compliance.

There is currently no mention in the documentation of support for *specific* features that are introduced after C++17.

Comment: Clang itself has a list of feature that are implemented, partially implemented, or not implemented yet: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: Which does say that modules are only partial supported, depending on which proposals you are interested in. There are 12 proposals listed under Modules, only 4 of which are fully supported by Clang 15, the other are either partially implemented, or not at all.